# How to store a bicycle for an extended period of time?

Tags: storage

What's the best way to store a bicycle for an extended period of time, say 2 months?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just make sure you give it a good once-over when you take it out to ride again. Make sure there's no rust and that everything that should be tight is tight and lubed is lubed.

Answer (score 11):

Doesn't really matter.  Just try to avoid really wet places.  I have left bikes in the garage for years.  Or for months at a time between rides.  (Road bike during the winter, while I ride my MTB to work, and vica versa).

I have left them standing on the floor.  Hanging from both wheels in the ceiling.  I recall a thread on hanging from just the front wheel and consensus was it did not matter.

Comment: Also try to get the bike dry and then a quick wipe over with a oiled cloth can help prevent resting.

Comment: Same thing: storing my 2 bikes in the garage for almost whole winter. Before storing: just a regular check with tires pressure to normal. I store them under tentage to save at least from some dust.

Answer (score 3):

Probably obvious, but don't leave it unattended outdoors, make sure it's properly locked and put somewhere where it's really hard to steal it.

Answer (score 2):

Clean the bike, air the tires to a normal pressure, and make sure everything's lubricated that should be. Try to store it in an inside location that you are in every day. Nothing like deciding to get your bike out of storage, only to find that it's missing! If it's going to be sitting on the floor, then some type of cover may be appropriate to keep any dust or dirt away from the bike. If you can secure it with the normal bike lock, that would be an added prevention of theft. After a couple of months, all you should need to do is air up the tires and look forward to a ride.