# Storing bicycle in a shed for the winter

Tags: winter, storage

I am living in Canada and it is the sad time of the year where I have to stop riding and store my bicycle for the winter. This summer I acquired a full carbon bike and I want to make sure it stays intact until the next summer.

Considering that the temperatures can drop to -30°C, is it bad if my bike is stored in a shed?

Comment: [search for "store bicycle](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/search?q=store+bicycle) on this site and you'll also find ["store bicycles outside during winter"](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/6181/how-to-store-bicycles-outside-during-winter)

Comment: Offtopic: why do you have to stop riding?

Comment: The main thing is to keep the bike dry.

Comment: @Michael 30 cm of snow :p

Answer (score 2):

http://velonews.competitor.com/2010/04/bikes-and-tech/technical-faq/technical-faq-carbon-in-cold-conditions_111530 summarises to "No problems"

> CF (carbon fibre) components are used extensively in launch/reentry
>   vehicles and satellites where the temperatures range from superheated
>   to near absolute zero. The ultra low CTE (Coefficient of Thermal
>   Expansion) of carbon fibre make it ideal for these temperature
>   extremes. I find it very hard to believe that a bicycle sustained
>   damage during winter storage in a cold garage – regardless of the
>   earthly location. I have seen “green” (not fully cured) paints and top
>   coats crack in extreme temperature conditions but never a CF composite
>   structure.

Although if your bike had water in it and that froze, you would have a different problem.   To deal with this, dry your bike, and hang your bike so it drains - often there are two breather/drainholes at the aft end of the chainstays... but do eyeball them first.

Comment: +1. I'm pretty sure that this question, or something quite similar, has been asked before. But this answer appears to be unique and is an almost canonical answer regarding the properties of carbon fibre ate extreme temperatures